# Inheriting parent class attributes in Mixin

Tags: typescript, inheritance, mixins, typescript-generics

I am trying to access a property from a inherited class inside a mixin

```
class BaseItem{
     public id:string;
     constructor(id:string) {
        this.id =id;  
     }
} 

abstract class ConfigMixin<K extends BaseItem>{
        public saveConfig() {
            const repo = getRepository(Entity);
            repo.update(
                { 
                    id: this.id // Typescript error
                },
                {
                    ...this.getConfig(),
                },
            );
        }
}

class BaseDevice extends BaseItem{
     constructor(id:string) {
        super(id);   
     }
} 
export interface BaseDevice extends ConfigMixin<BaseDevice> {}
applyMixins(BaseDevice , [ConfigMixin]);
```

However im recieving the following error:
TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ORCASmartLightConfig'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

1. **Stick to the strict encapsulation of mixins.** Mixins are meant to be self-standing, not knowing about where they will be mixed in. That means that a mixin should not know that it has been mixed to a class that has an `id` field:

```js
// The first approach sticks to the strict encapsulation of mixins
export abstract class ConfigMixin {
  // Your mixin will receive all the things it needs as parameters
  // so every time you call saveConfig you need to pass the id
  public saveConfig(id: string) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}

// The base class
class BaseItem {
  constructor(public id: string) {}
}

// An implementation of subclass of BaseItem
export class BaseDevice extends BaseItem {}

// Here we tell TypeScript that BaseDevice has ConfigMixin mixed in
export interface BaseDevice extends ConfigMixin {}

// And finally we apply the ConfigMixin
applyMixins(BaseDevice, [ConfigMixin]);
```

[Link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBUAsFNQZ2gYwPYDsAmoCGAHHAnZLRSeAFwEtEBrOUM5emc-Ks0aVRXOAVwBsslNKGQAzUAFsKADwqo4AKGgycyfOywAjOGXzF2iQXDoBhNGIoBzALKz5oAN6LQoEKACayXvin3UoADuFPz8oPhI0BQAbrBYoUywZJDyVnQU7KjQ0Oh0WHQ4WPqS0GTQ+EquOLxa-FTwWLHmqJZWABQU6ABcLKkAlE4urqAoCsj80AB0-MjtnX0A3EMAvoqriu5QsFr5sEb5SvsmoABCuwCSZZKDrqO6+LyIDPht1bX1nT33-U6r6+4AQQCFEkOAmJVQZCEFBE4ngNSOdDhZwQl2gkmUqnUhmMdBR0AAItBolRYCoyhg8Rcrr9FBswAAJcqwQJJaAJcAATxw0AAyohWDh2MkhKddkSSYhYJB8qBmq07HIAtIZDlQPJMWoNOrIeUxMRYPiJaSODIKbk5RZrIqHI5-mAAKotbG8VBCdmcoIZUjJCh5PCEYikLk8-mC9jBBKoZCGZCgwQOQIwVD00Cc7zYCL0fCc1L0Rgqhzy63+L3JbAjXFMUXoZDQOjR9gy2Lq9Ca7GVg6gXlxwnEk129va+RlfD6qXd3vGifkzgW4u2UuD1NAzCWN2hT2s7B4fie5KwBc2lO4MGc49wNpG-tSgA0oAA2kf-ABdRaKIA)

2. **Trick TypeScript!** In this case the resulting code is more similar to your original approach, but it comes with a drawback:

```js
// The second approach makes use of an abstract class field
export abstract class ConfigMixin {
  public abstract id: string;

  public saveConfig() {
    console.log(this.id);
  }
}

// The base class
class BaseItem {
  constructor(public id: string) {}
}

// An implementation of subclass of BaseItem
export class BaseDevice extends BaseItem {}

// Here we tell TypeScript that BaseDevice has ConfigMixin mixed in
export interface BaseDevice extends ConfigMixin {}

// NOW THE DRAWBACK
//
// Unfortunately with this approach TypeScript will not complain when
// you are trying to mixin ConfigMixin with a class that does not have id
export class SomeDevice {}
export interface SomeDevice extends ConfigMixin {}

// And finally we apply the ConfigMixin
applyMixins(BaseDevice, [ConfigMixin]);
applyMixins(SomeDevice, [ConfigMixin]);
```

[Link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=71#code/PTAEBUAsFNQMwJYCcDOAXUBDADtpB7TAY0lAFtMBraFUAVxVnziwDssAjdJYjIgG0wpaiaPwAmAKGgAPbPiQZMXNDyJ9Bw0AGF8rRAHMAsghkJ2Ab0mhQ2Oh34Iinbr1AJxALlDdzBgNyS1rb2js4omABu0Lr6CAYAFACUoFY2NkR6KPj80AB0-PiJaJAIKHkeSYE2AL6SdZIgEDCgHEKwAkIokp1aAELtAJJo0GSpwZms3HTqCgl2Dk7uXj6qfikWdQ1NAILsCGTYuWTQrGiYaAh6oMw%209r20twOMw6PScgoaXaDP0AAi0EiTlgshGrHEtF%20rzGmyCTQAEtAkLAAO6wEb8fgQACe2GgAGUiEgENgMCULj92gCgURYJAhDo9IYTGZ2GRTNBxO5WO95IpuSMkHBiLBftTgaBQacIYy4sZTOZUtswABVfSfOisC5ibGgFEIEqgEplLC4AjEUjgXEEokkjD6zGgVj4Pj4Q6CRUomA8prY-B0LDIo1IbF%20I34cgK9ixZlRvUG0iYUAPI30jDifA0J0u0D06LLXmfZOaWj4t3-QES2GyPkYcyC4W00Blk7iptS8G0GPxFmK2GNMB7LmILWY3Vo01HXUlWDd%20WsyQ4Ke9qYJMWV2kAGlAAG05yuALpVSRAA)